# tangent line parallel to vector

Tags: geometry

What is the equation of the line tangent to the intersection of the surface $z=\arctan(xy)$ with the plane $x=2$, at the point $(2, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{\pi}{4})$ ?

The partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} =\dfrac{x}{1+x^2y^2}$, evaluated at $(2, \frac{1}{2})$, is equal to $1$. How can this calculation show that the line is parallel to the vector $v=(0, 1, 1)$ ? That is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the functions $f(x,y,z)=\arctan(xy)-z=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=2-x=0$.

First, we calculate the gradients (the vector with the partial derivatives as components):

$\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{y}{1+(xy)^2} \\ \frac{x}{1+(xy)^2} \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$

$\nabla g=(-1,0,0)$

Then, we evaluate the gradients at the given point:

$\nabla f$ evaluated at $(2,\frac12,\frac{\pi}{4})$ gives $(\frac14, 1, -1)$. $\nabla g$ evaluated gives $(-1,0,0)$.

Last, we calculate the cross product (a vector that is perpendicular to both vectors) of $(\frac14,1,-1)$ and $(-1,0,0)$, which is $(0,1,1)$.

The equation of the line is

$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ \frac12 \\ \frac{\pi}{4}\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$